# Moved marker disappears when using Marker Clusterer

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have an application that has a large number of markers (hence the desire to use Marker Clusterer), but I want to allow the user to move the marker around. Unfortunately, the marker disappears after it has been moved and you zoom out / in. Precisely, these are the steps that reproduce the problem:

1. Create all the markers / add them to a marker clusterer object.
2. Zoom in to see an individual marker.
3. Move the marker to a new location.
4. Zoom out until the clustering kicks in (and groups the moved marker with at least one other marker)
5. Zoom back in to see the marker that was moved.

I would expect the marker to still be there after zooming back in, but it is not. After step 3, the marker remains visible -- it only disappears after zooming out and then back in. The clustering still counts the marker correctly (it appears in the cluster total when zoomed out), but the marker doesn't ever appear again.

I have tried using the latest versions of MarkerClusterer and MarkerClustererPlus and I'm dealing with v3 of the maps API. Additionally, I have an event listener that calls `repaint` on the cluster after a marker `dragend` occurs (thinking that a `repaint` would cause the marker to be placed proper).

[**Edit**]
A minimal example (based on the Marker Clusterer example) that demonstrates the problem can be found [here](http://www.haz.ca/MarkerClustererExample.html). The only things changed from [this example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/simple_example.html) are the lines including the javascript libraries (made absolute links), and adding `draggable: true` to the marker options. Following the above 5 steps should reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have two silly ideas. First, try google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'). The second idea might work if you keep a reference to all markers: In a listener for zoomChanged, for all markers, make it setVisible(true). If "large number" is really large, though, this is impractical.

Comment: When do you propose the trigger be fired? In the dragend event listener?

Comment: I'm not sure what would work because I haven't reproduced your page and defect over here. If the marker was always still visible after finishing dragging, I say it's pointless to add any listener to dragend. I think that because the disappearance has to do with zooming out and in, try adding this line: google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoomChanged', function() { trigger resize / setVisible });

Comment: The resize trigger doesn't seem to work, and the fact that the marker remains visible after dragging makes me thing that visibility isn't an issue. I think it has more to do with the map associated with the marker (from what I can tell, that's how MarkerClusterer hides / shows things). I have added an example to the question.

Comment: There are other cases where the behavior is unexpected. For example, zoom out twice and nothing shows up in the Americas. There are more than ten in North America. I don't really trust the clusterer. I give up on your question, sorry :(

Comment: Aye, that's another somewhat annoying bug (likely unrelated to the draggable issue). Fortunately it's not really a problem in my application. Thanks for giving it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that has been reported to the google maps api team (issue # 167).  See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/issues/detail?id=167&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Fixed%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

It is triggered any time by a setMap(map) followed by any sort of marker movement (including animation) followed by a setMap(null).  At that point the marker cannot be shown again.

Comment: See my earlier post on so re similar behavior (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981763/moved-marker-disappears-when-using-marker-clusterer/10269341#10269341]

Comment: Aye, I'm the author of 167. Hopefully things will get sorted out soon.

Comment: Google maps API team has now fixed the bug. [Here is the report](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4052).